# Why is it necessary to call PropertyChanged in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing my first MVVM WPF application.

In all my model code for properties in my view, I call code for IPropertyChanged. My code works, but I don't understand why I am doing it.

Why doesn't .NET just "know" that property value has changed? Why do I have to call PropertyChanged explicitly for the UI to refresh?

Comment: How should we answer this? You need to ask the .NET devs. But in general why should we always have a PropertyChanged by default, if we don't need it in every particular case.

Comment: 'Why doesn't .Net just "know"' - well, how *could* it know? It's up to you what you do in your getters/setters, and with the underlying fields, so how could .NET possible know when exactly a property changed event must be issued for any given property?

Comment: "Why doesn't .Net just "know""  - because it is a programming framework with certain limitations, not **magic**. if you want sort of magic - try [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged)

Comment: @ASh: And even that magic cannot know when a property changes as a result of some internal state change that is not triggered by the property's setter.

Comment: @FINDarkside: Well, only for dependency properties on dependency objects. But those implement pretty much the same thing behind the scenes as INPC.

Answer (score 3):

You're having an incorrect perspective here. .NET doesn't know that data are changed. Changing a property value is merely putting a new content into a memory location. There is no way for any other part of code, including the framework (which is again just a common code) to know that the memory content has changed.

In order to make others aware, you normally implement the Observable pattern. The object which holds the changing value allows other objects to add themselves to a list of "observers".

```
// principal solution, not a real code
class DataClass
{
    List observers;

    public void Add(observer)
    {
        observers.Add(observer);
    }
}
```

Then, when a value it contains changes, it calls a method on each of the observers:

```
// Again the principal code, not real solution
class DataClass
{
    private int data;

    public void SetData(int value)
    {
        data = value; // Nobody knows this has happened

        // And now the others should be notified
        foreach (observer in observers)
        {
            observer.NotifyDataChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

In WPF applications, UI elements are the observers. You are connecting them with your data classes. `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface is the formal way to implement Observable pattern in this case.

Your data classes will give UI a chance to notice that the data have been modified and to refresh content of UI controls accordingly.

Comment: He just used the wrong term. What he's probably asking is that why don't properties automatically implement PropertyChanged.

Comment: I'm not sure... Anyway, I have tried to explain entire mechanism so that there are no misunderstandings.

Answer (score 2):

It is only necessary to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for a data-bound property when you intend to set the source property dynamically at runtime and want the view to be "automatically" notified of this change.

If you don't raise this event, WPF cannot be supposed to know when to update the data-bound value in the view.

Behind the scenes, WPF subscribes to this event and handles the refresh functionality in the view for you "automatically". All you need to do is to tell it when to refresh the target property and the way you do this is to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Hopefully this answers your question.